# .NET core API controller never recieves body from Angular client

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an order API. Here I'm trying to add the order from the user so it takes in a full Order object. Here's the method in my controller:

```
 [HttpPost("addOrder")]
 public IActionResult addOrder([FromBody] Order order)
```

Here's my models @ server side:

```
public class Order
{
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public double TotalOrder { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
    public Order()
    {
        OrderItems = new List<OrderItem>();
    }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CartId")]
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string adress { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to test my method via Postman with the following body it reaches my API and the whole Order is included in my Order parameter:

```
{
    "OrderId": "OrderIDTest",
    "User": {
        "firstName": "FNT",
        "lastName": "LNT",
        "adress": "AT"
    },
    "TotalOrder": "999",
    "OrderItems": [
            {
                "ProductName": "Shoe 1",
                "Price": "99",
                "Quantity": 2
            },
             {
                "ProductName": "Shoe 2",
                "Price": "299",
                "Quantity": 4
            }
        ]
   }
```

but when I send it through my Angular, I never reaches my addOrder endpoints. Here's the object I'm sending printed out in a consolelog:

[image: Object from Angular Client:]

My Angular Service:

```
createOrder(order: Order) {
console.log(order);
let header = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
return this.HttpClient.post("https://localhost:44369/api/order/addOrder", order, { headers: header });
```

}

btw I know address is wrongly spelled

Comment: Please share the complete request from Network tab.

Comment: It never gets added but the line above (console.log(order)) does gets outprinted on button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem might be
Request is not subscribed, this is one of the common issues. That's why request never goes out to the Api.

Please share the network request so i can better analyze.

Comment: Clicking the button does go to the createOrder method (it prints out the object on each click) but no request gets added under the network tab

Comment: Now I understood you and you were correct. I needed to subscribe to the request first